# Partial Integration - Where did I go wrong?

Tags: analysis, integration

For a Homework, I need $\int \frac{x}{(x-1)^2} dx$ as an intermediate result. Using partial integration, I derive $x$ and integrate $\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$, getting: $$ \frac{-x}{x-1} + \int \frac{1}{x-1} dx = \ln(x-1)+\frac{x}{x-1} $$
WolframAlpha tells me this is wrong (it gives me $\frac{1}{1-x}$ where I have $\frac{x}{x-1}$). If I and WA disagree the error is usually somewhere on my side. Unfortunately WA uses partial fractions there instead of partial integration, so I'm not sure which step I screwed up. Supposedly $\int f'g dx =  fg - \int fg' dx$ right?

(I leave the constant +C out because it's not relevant for the problem I need this for).

Comment: You lost the $-$ in going from $-x/(x-1)$ to $x/(x-1)$.  Apart from that, you and WA agree: note that $x/(x-1)$ and $1/(x-1)$ differ by a constant

Comment: $\dfrac{x}{x-1}$ is the same as $\dfrac{1}{x-1}+\text{constant}$, where the "constant" is $1$.

Comment: By the way, it might have been easier to substitute $u=x-1$, then divide through and integrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ve a sign error: you should have $$\ln(x-1)-\frac{x}{x-1}\;.$$

Now note that

$$\frac{x}{x-1}=1+\frac1{x-1}\;,$$

so your (corrected) answer can be written $$\ln(x-1)-1-\frac1{x-1}=\ln(x-1)+\frac1{1-x}-1\;.$$

Your (corrected) answer differs from WA’s by a constant, which is absorbed in the constant of integration; both are perfectly good antiderivatives of the given function.

Comment: Thanks. I "fixed" the sign when I wrote this by accident (I had it right in my notes, then for some reason when I wrote it here I thought it was wrong).

Answer (score 0):

the  result   is  :   $\ln|x-1| - \frac x{x-1}  +  C$   where  $C$  is  some  constant.
If  $C=1$   you  get   :  $\ln |x-1| +  \frac 1{1-x}$ 
The  finaly  result  can  be  expressed :
$$F(x) = \ln |x-1| +  \frac 1{1-x} +  \lambda$$   where $\lambda$  is  some constant.
Precesely :
 $$F(x) = \ln (x-1) +  \frac 1{1-x} +  \lambda$$ on  the  intervale $]1,+\infty[$
and:
$$F(x) = \ln (1-x) +  \frac 1{1-x} +  \lambda$$   on  the  intervale: $]-\infty ,1[$